# C++ how to call a method defined in a class directly where only the reference to the class is returned by another function

Tags: c++, class, reference, compiler-errors

In my program, I have a grid class (e.g. `myGrid`) and I could obtain a reference to a cell (a class) by overloading the `operator()`. My problem is each time I call this `myGrid(x, y)` which returns a reference to a cell, I need to claim a cell reference.

```
 cell& myCell = myGrid(x,y);
 myCell.status = currentStatus;
```

I got an error by doing this:

```
(myGrid(x,y)).status = currentStatus;
```

I need to use the function defined in cell very frequently. Thus, each time I need to claim a cell reference which makes my code look urgly. Is there any elegant way to solve the problem? Thanks very much. Cheers!

Sorry. There is a typo. Let's assume status is a public varible in cell and assume currentStatus is a variable of the same type as status.

Grid is a predefined class and I don't have the right to modify it. It returns a reference to cell.
E.g. cell& operator()(int x, int y)

Sorry for the chaos. myGrid(x,y).status works. I made a mistake somewhere before. When I complied it, the error occurred in this line. Thanks very much!

Comment: This is a question more about the `status()` method. What is its signature?

Comment: what is the error, and what is `status()`'s return type and signature?

Comment: Err, based on the information you've given, it seems like you should make status() return a reference to whatever the type of currentStatus is. But you should really provide more information and frankly, it doesn't look like a good design. Why not make it status(currentStatus)?

Answer (score 0):

the object of function-myGrid(x,y) return ,maybe out of scope.
I mean, the object you return may be a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

How your `operator()` defined (signature)? What is the signature of `status`? They should be `cell& operator() (int x, int y);` and `int& status();`. Provide minimal example that doesn't work.

And the best way and elegant is to use explicit methods:

```
myGrid.GetCell(x, y).SetStatus(s);
```

This is much more readable and supportable. Also, using getter/setter instead of returning a reference may allow you control point where value changed - you may log there or set a breakpoint. Returning reference is poor practice - you may never be sure will it be changed or only read after.

Comment: "returning reference is poor practice" is controversial, to say the least!